# Is a trip to USA for 49 days to see gf too long?

Tags: usa, international-travel

My bf is coming to visit for some part of the summer for some much needed R&R. He is from the UK and I am in the US. We have been together for more than a year. Just wondering if we are going to have any hiccups. He has come here previously and left when he said he would, as well. :-) We plan on being 100% honest but would like advice as we have never stayed for longer than 2 weeks. Thanks!

Comment: It would help you to have written approval that he can have that leave from school/work, and that he can stay with you that long (from homeowner, landlord etc) and as always, a return ticket.

Comment: What if he is self employed? He works mainly for one guy, but work is slow in the summertime so he is able to stay for longer vs in the winter. Can he just tell this to them if they ask?

Comment: It’s also my house, so I obviously give him permission to stay with me, and they know he is staying with me. We also plan on traveling and doing all sorts!

Comment: The reason I chose those examples is because to gain entry, the officers have to be confident the person will return home after the visit, the more proof he can provide that he will actually go back, the ties that he has to the UK, the better. As long as he can prove that, the amount of time is fine!

Comment: It’s kind of difficult to prove that because he is self employed. That’s why I am looking for advice in that case, for someone who isn’t employed in a traditional sense or someone who is lacking in strong ties back to the UK.

Comment: "I obviously give him permission to stay with me". It's only obvious if BF can produce a letter of invitation.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I see what you mean I’m just confused as I don’t see the big deal in claiming that in a letter if he has stayed with me previously with no such documentation with zero issues. What do I even say in this letter? “I have asked my bf to stay with me for x days?”

Comment: I mean that in previous questions it has been mentioned that the person visiting should have a letter of invitation from the person they claim to be staying with. "It's obvious" does not constitute proof. The letter is from you to him, not from you to the government. "Dear John, I am inviting you to stay with me at ...  from ... to ...".

Comment: I see, this just tells them that he is invited to stay with me vs not having any place to go? Thanks so much!

Comment: Does his business have books and a bank account that would demonstrate that it is reasonable to suspend it for a few weeks at the time he is visiting, but that he needs to get back to run it the rest of the year?

Answer (score 5):

Write a letter like this, with your name, address, and phone number at the top:

> To whom it may concern:
>   I am an American citizen. *boyfriend's name* will be
>   staying as a guest in my home for the dates of *start-date* to
>   *end-date*, after which he will be returning to the UK to resume working with *work-provider*.
>   Signed: *your name*

And have your boyfriend's work-provider sign a letter like this, with their name, address, and phone number at the top, and some details about the work-provider's line of business (including a website, if they have one):

> To whom it may concern:
>   *boyfriend's name* has been working for me on a contractual basis since *whenever*, and he will be working for me again from *some date shortly after his return*.

Your boyfriend can show these to immigration when he lands. Make sure you are contactable by phone when your boyfriend arrives in the US. If possible, ask the work-provider to be contactable at the same time.

**Edited to add:** As jcaron points out in the comments, your boyfriend should only show these to the immigration officer if he is asked. And he should certainly have a return plane ticket that he can show if asked.

Comment: Let’s make it clear that this information should be presented to the CBP officer only if they start asking questions. It is quite possible that they won’t go beyond the usual “how are you today / what is the purpose of your stay / how long are you planning to stay”, though the longer stay and the mention of “girlfriend” make a few additional questions probable. A booked return ticket and proof of ties to the UK (work, lease for flat/house...) should be at hand.

Comment: @jcaron: Yes, you are quite right. I have edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: If I live at home, should the letter come from my mom? She’s completely fine with him coming here. Can I just write it so they know where he is meant to be staying?

Comment: @Plumdiggy: I don't see why your mother should write it. I assume you are an adult.

Answer (score 2):

From personal experience I've stayed for the full VWP days to see my girlfriend when she lived in the States. I also went a few times for less amounts of time (1-2 weeks)

You get a bit more questioning but if you're honest you're fine. Having some connection like a job or uni to go back to helps. I didn't many ties to go back to as I'd just finished college, apart from family when I went for 3 months so the IO was pretty aggressive with the questioning which is understandable, but I just answered everything honestly. Make sure the return flights are booked.

I never used a letter like TonyK says but it may help.

Just make sure he doesn't lie, the truth always comes out and could make him illegible for the VWP in future.

Comment: This is such great advice thank you so much! And we will have the letter just incase. I am hopeful it will all be okay since he is not even staying for the full VWP. I except questions but nothing wild or crazy and we will be 100% honest. :-)

Comment: I am also wondering, how much money should he plan to bring? Since he is staying with me, that saves us a lot of money we wouldn’t otherwise have. I’m thinking 1500-2000 should be sufficient since it’s just spending money. Thanks in advance for the thoughtful responses!

Comment: They didn't ask me about my money to be honest, I only had about $1000, my mum was sending me some spend weekly too. Maybe having a credit card might help if he gets a money question, can say he had $2000 and a credit card if needed. $1000 a month seems more than reasonable to say he wont be paying for accommodation.

Comment: Thank you BritishSam, we taking your advice...as long as we are honest I don’t think 49 days is long at all.

Comment: I think you'll be fine :) plus they've got your address if there is an over stay!

Comment: Hey BritishSam I forgot to mention that we booked a 3 week flight months ago before hearing back from his job somewhat prematurely. we only recently found out he has been allowed time to stay til the end of Aug. considering the nature of his job being slow in the summer. We tried to call to change it but we’re told it will be an extra 700 pound! Any advice?

Comment: Have a look what a single flight home will cost and not use the original return? Can show the single flight home to the immigration officer if he gets asked. I was forced to change my flight as I actually had it booked for a day over what I was allowed stay. Immigration officer saw it and told me to change it as soon as possible, I just booked a single as it was cheaper than changing.

Comment: There was one for 300 pound so that’s not bad...can he just explain to them what happened just as long as he has a return ticket for the end of Aug?

Comment: It's a return flight back to the UK when he says he's going back, wont have to explain the other booking etc. Just if they ask to see his return flight show the new one.